# My mouseover, mouseleave doesnt work

Tags: jquery, asp.net, events

```
$("document").ready(function () {
       $('#eventTarget').bind("mouseover", changeColor);//This doesnt work
       $('#eventTarget').bind("mouseleave", changeColor);//This doesnt work

       $('#eventTarget').bind("click", function(){   //This code works
              $('#eventTarget').unbind("mouseover", changeColor);
              $('#eventTarget').unbind("mouseleave", changeColor);
              $('#eventTarget').html("<p> click event handler Canceled</p>");
       }); 
    });
  function changeColor(evt) {
      $('#eventTarget').toggleClass("highlight");
    }
```

CSS:

```
.highlight
{
    background-color:Red
}
.normal
{ 
    background-color:Yellow

}
```

HTML body:

```
    <div id="eventTarget" class="normal">
    HardCoreProg...

* All activity
* Subscriptions
* Recommendations
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your highlight CSS class as follows:

```
.highlight
{
    background-color:Red !important;
}
```

As a bonus, use the `hover` function to bind to both mouseover and mouseleave events with one line of code:

```
$('#eventTarget').hover(changeColor, changeColor);
```

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript is fine, your problem is that the `highlight` and `normal` CSS classes are fighting each other for control of `background-color`. If you force the issue with `!important`:

```
.highlight {
    background-color: Red !important
}
```

Then it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/LQqgb/

Answer (score -1):

Hold on, you don't need to use `!important` just to ensure that a style definition is applied. Try adding weight to your CSS selector by making it more specific -- it will do what you want now, and you'll still be able to override it later on in your CSS file if you want.

```
#eventTarget.highlight {
    background-color: red;
}

.normal {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

For more information about how CSS specificity works, check out this article on Smashing Magazine: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

*Edit: Maybe I should have linked to the W3C's document on specificity instead? http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity*