# bind - mouseover on ul list

Tags: jquery, bind, html-lists

I have this situation:

```
<ul id="country_list"onmouseover="cl();">

function cl(){ 
// something to do 
}
```

This function goes but not sounds.

So I do this:

```
$('#country_list').bind('mouseover', function () { // do what you want to do on mouse over });
```

but the function doesn't work!!!

For the solution I have seen this question [My mouseover, mouseleave doesnt work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049182/my-mouseover-mouseleave-doesnt-work) and I have tried all the suggestions, but nothing !

Why???

In the question called [variables and jquery: how capture value and use them (part 3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421323/variables-and-jquery-how-capture-value-and-use-them-part-3) you can find all my codex for the `function cl()`.

thanks

Comment: You want us to find that question ourselves? C'mon we're programmers, we're lazy (or we would have gotten a job where we actually had to do hard labor ;) ). On a more serious note: What errors do you get? Does not work is kinda vague.

Comment: it works here http://jsfiddle.net/qGvAf/3/

Comment: I'm betting this is a problem with not using the doc ready function and the script being above the UL tag.

Comment: Ok, I have seen the examples, and I 'll do an error, but it doesn't work for me.

Pheraps is for this  *...not using the doc ready function...*  Why I must use it? And where?  And why `<ul id="country_list"onmouseover="cl();">` works?

Sorry, but write in (bad) English need a lot of time for me.

Comment: for  PeeHaa. I don't have errors, it semplify doesn't see the bind event. thanks

Comment: @ulisse a browser reads up to down, if you try to find a DOM element before it actually exists it wont work, what the DOM-ready method does is it query all methods to run as fast as the browser actually has a DOM to work with. a simple solution is just add your javascript as far down on your page as you can (right before </body> is the lowest you can). will work great.

Comment: Ok sorry but I must work with translator... (!!!). If I put my script under html it works. If i put it in the head it doesn'work. I understand the question about loading. So if I want to use before my ul list i should use $(document).ready(). It's true? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Is there any specific reason you are using `mouseover()`? I would recommend [`hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/):

```
$('#country_list').hover(function () {
    // Do something
    alert('Im doing something!');
});
```

Further more:

```
$('#country_list').hover(function () {
    // Do something on mouseover
    alert('Cursor landed on the object');
}, function () {
    // Do something on mouseout
    alert('Cursor left the object');
});
```

**A side note:** If this doesn't work, then most likely the problem is somewhere else. Maybe you forgot to include jQuery in general or there is a fundamental JS issue somewhere.